# Type alias for a union of two @runtime_checkable Protocols triggers mypy's "Cannot use parameterized generics in instance checks"

Tags: python, mypy, type-hinting

Here's my code, simplified a lot ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=master&python=3.12&gist=02326c887487ca6c05e31867ddf66412), [using `_typeshed.SupportsTrunc`](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=master&python=3.12&gist=0b719a8f72ee21851b84492a81a78629)):

```py
from typing import Protocol, runtime_checkable, SupportsIndex, SupportsInt


@runtime_checkable
class SupportsTrunc(Protocol):
    
    def __trunc__(self) -> int:
        ...


_ConvertibleToInt = SupportsInt | SupportsIndex | SupportsTrunc
```

```py
def f(o: object) -> None:
    if isinstance(o, _ConvertibleToInt):
        # error: Parameterized generics cannot be used with class or instance checks
        # error: Argument 2 to "isinstance" has incompatible type "<typing special form>"; expected "_ClassInfo"
        ...
```

All of the three `Protocol`s [are `@runtime_checkable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#protocols). As far as I'm aware, these are clearly not parameterized as mypy claimed. What am I doing wrong? Or is this a mypy bug?

---

Thanks to @wjandrea, I have found a more minimal example:

```py
from typing import SupportsIndex, SupportsInt

_ConvertibleToInt = SupportsInt | SupportsIndex

def f(o: object) -> None:
    if isinstance(o, _ConvertibleToInt):  # error
        ...
```

The same error does not happen if there is no alias ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=master&python=3.12&gist=a8c09fe38ce5c66773a4ff6583a0aa4d)):

```py
def f(o: object) -> None:
    if isinstance(o, SupportsInt | SupportsIndex):  # fine
        ...
```

...or if the alias is for one `Protocol` and not a union ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=master&python=3.12&gist=4ccd4accb20a6b36784103408d999071)):

```py
_ConvertibleToInt = SupportsInt

def f(o: object) -> None:
    if isinstance(o, _ConvertibleToInt):  # fine
        ...
```

A union of the same `Protocol` repeated twice still triggers this error ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=master&python=3.12&gist=dedf6e8e884fb14a1fbe0fc0c799a99d)):

```py
_ConvertibleToInt = SupportsInt | SupportsInt

def f(o: object) -> None:
    if isinstance(o, _ConvertibleToInt):  # error
        ...
```

Comment: I'm not a Mypy expert, but FWIW, you can remove `SupportsTrunc` and still get the same errors. ([playground](https://mypy-play.net/?flags=strict&mypy=master&python=3.12&gist=b535118780e7550a99def841b6731d32))

Comment: @wjandrea Thanks. More details added to the question.

Comment: Looks like a bug: union of plain types is definitely not a parametrized generic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a bug (thanks @STerliakov for the confirmation). Reported at [mypy/#16707](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/16707).